# android - GCM Notification Dynamic Large Icon not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, bitmapfactory

I am trying to load a dynamic large icon for my GCM push notification. But it always returns null. Here is my code. The `BitmapFactory.decode()` always returns null. I checked this code to fetch some icon for image view and it works fine in that case, but not in my case.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(downloadBitmap(url))
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(message);


static public Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://files.softicons.com/download/system-icons/crystal-project-icons-by-everaldo-coelho/png/22x22/apps/skype.png");
         Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url); 
                return null;
            }

            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = entity.getContent(); 
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(inputStream));
                    return bitmap;
                } finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();  
                    }
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
            getRequest.abort();
            Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url + e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                client.close();
            }
        }
         return bitmap;
    }

    static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
        public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
            super(inputStream);
        }

        @Override
        public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
            long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
            while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
                long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
                if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                      int num_byte = read();
                      if (num_byte < 0) {
                          break;  // we reached EOF
                      } else {
                          bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                      }
               }
                totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
            }
            return totalBytesSkipped;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working... It was an issue with android Emulator. I was using Emulator 2.2. As sson as I switched it to a newer version it started to work